# Mongo: How to drop duplicates in (very) large collection?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection that's 50+ gb large and contains 35+ million documents. I'm using Mongo 3.4. There's an unknown number of duplicates that I'm trying to remove. Here's the structure of a typical document:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('609328685fd8ae473473eb9a'),
    'ogc_fid': 1054118,
    'path': '/us/ca/san-diego/camp-pendleton/1054118'
}
```

I'm using the following aggregation to remove the duplicates, filtering on the `path` field:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$path", 
            "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } 
        }}, 
        { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } },
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]

)
```

After a few minutes, however, the Mongo shell returns the following error:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error opening file \"/Users/data/db/_tmp/extsort.1651\": errno:24 Too many open files",
    "code" : 16818,
    "codeName" : "Location16818"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
@(shell):1:1
```

Notably, I already maximized the allowable number of open documents by starting the Mongo server with:

```
sudo ulimit -n 64000 && mongod
```

Is there any way to resolve this error. Or is there a better way to parse a large collection and drop duplicates?

Comment: 64000 is the minimum recommended for a mongodb cluster, is there a reason you can't make that larger?

Comment: @Joe didn't make it larger since, from my understanding, that's the max amount allowed by Mac OS.

Comment: Your ulimit setting is incorrect and doesn't do anything. Read the documentation for the right way to configure it.